# Why do similar assembly instructions cause neither instruction to execute on Sandybridge?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86, kernel

I am attempting to write a kernel driver for PCIe on x86 Intel Sandybridge using gcc 11.3. My end goal is to send a single 64 byte data write, and I have a 32 byte write working. When I essentially duplicate the code for the 32 byte write, the processor fails to send a pcie packet.

**What works:**

I have kernel space mapped to user space, and I can execute 32 byte writes with the following code:

```
// data points to an uint32 arr of length 8 (32 bytes total)
// addr points to the kernel-mapped, write-combine address in PCIe memory

void write_32(uint8_t *data, uint8_t *addr)
{
    asm volatile (
                  "vmovdqa %[data_lo],  %%ymm1    \n\t"
                  "vmovdqa %%ymm1,      %[addr_lo] \n\t"

                   // Outputs
                   : [addr_lo]  "=m"(* addr)

                   // Inputs 
                   : [data_lo]  "m"(* data)

                   // Clobbers
                   : "memory"

                  );
}
```

This bit of code works great, and I can see 32 bytes being written to the PCIe memory, which is hosted on an Intel FPGA that is configured for 64 byte payloads.

**What breaks:**

I wrote a similar 64 byte function. Since I am working on an old SandyBridge, I must use two 32 byte moves rather than a single 64 byte. When I call this function, the processor does not send *any* pcie packet. Ideally, this transaction would send one 64 byte payload rather than two 32 byte payloads to reduce overhead, but at this point I would take two 32 byte payloads.

```
// data points to an uint32 arr of length 16 (64 bytes total)
// addr points to the kernel-mapped, write-combine address in PCIe memory

static int write_64(uint8_t *data, void __iomem *addr)
{
    // Move data to 256-bit ymm1 register.
    uint8_t *data_upper      = data + 32;
    void __iomem *addr_upper = addr + 32;


    asm volatile (
                 "vmovdqa   %[data_lo], %%ymm3      \n\t"
                 "vmovdqa   %[data_hi], %%ymm4      \n\t"
                 "vmovntdq  %%ymm3,     %[addr_lo]  \n\t"
                 "vmovntdq  %%ymm4,     %[addr_hi]  \n\t"

                // Outputs 
                 :  [addr_lo]   "=m"(*(volatile uint8_t * __force) addr),
                    [addr_hi]   "=m"(*(volatile uint8_t * __force) addr_upper)

                 // Inputs
                 : [data_lo]    "m"(*(volatile const char (*__force)[32]) data),
                   [data_hi]    "m"(*(volatile const char (*__force)[32]) data_upper)
                 // Clobbers
                 : "ymm3",
                   "ymm4",
                   "memory"
                 
                );
    return 0;
}
```

Memory Initialization:

```
static int chr_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    struct chr_dev_bookkeep *chr_dev_bk;
    struct dev_bookkeep *dev_bk;
    unsigned long len, pfn;
    int ret;
    pgoff_t pgoff;

    len = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    pgoff = vma->vm_pgoff;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Mapping %ld bytes\n", len);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Start: %ld   End: %ld\n", vma->vm_start, vma->vm_end);
    chr_dev_bk = filp->private_data;
    dev_bk = chr_dev_bk->dev_bk;

    if ((len == 0) || (len+pgoff) > dev_bk->kmem_info.size) {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    vma->vm_ops = &intel_fpga_vm_ops;
    vma->vm_flags |= VM_PFNMAP | VM_DONTCOPY | VM_DONTEXPAND;
    //vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_writecombine(vma->vm_page_prot);
    vma->vm_private_data = dev_bk;
    //PFN: Page frame number 

    pfn = __pa(dev_bk->kmem_info.virt_addr + (pgoff<<PAGE_SHIFT))>>PAGE_SHIFT;
    ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pfn, len, vma->vm_page_prot);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "could not remap kernel buffer to user-space.");
        return -ENXIO;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A few things that I've confirmed:

1. A hex dump of the 64 bytes to be written is indeed the expected data to be sent
2. Printing out the address shows that the address is 32B aligned, as expected
3. Commenting out a single 'vmovntdq' line is enough to write half the data into the upper half or lower half of the 64B word line in the PCIe memory
4. Checking the assigned memory with lspci and cat pat_memtype_list shows that the assigned memory locations for the pcie bar are write-combined, as expected.

Calling the two moves individually works fine. In other words, I can write the lower half of data to the lower address in memory, and I can write the upper half of data to the upper address in memory. The assembly for the full code is as expected: two moves into a register, and then two moves into memory:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eKaxP5e8z

Interestingly enough, if I turn on optimization via -O3, the processor still sends a single 32 byte write with data_lo using the same code as above:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bGGGb8fh9

Comment: Unrelated to PCIe transactions, but forgot to declare clobbers on YMM1 and YMM2.  You're running this in user-space (without the kernel's `-mgeneral-regs-only` build option), not inside `kernel_fpu_begin()` / your code / `kernel_fpu_end()` in the kernel.  Thus you need to tell the compiler about vector registers you overwrite, just like you would integer regs.  Or use intrinsics.

Comment: When you enable optimization, the UB of a non-`void` function without a C++ `return` statement bites you: as you can see in the 2nd Godbolt link, there's no `ret` instruction in the asm; the compiler assumes a `__builtin_unreachable()` after the asm statement.   Also, you wrote `[addr_hi]` instead of `%[addr_hi]`, so it compiles with GCC but won't assemble.  And with `int *data`, `+32` offsets by 128 bytes.

Comment: Anyway, for PCIe writes, your memory region should be mapped WC, and you should be using `VMOVNTDQ`.  I thought regular stores might do write-combining on WC memory, but a pair of NT stores to the two halves of a cache-line should produce a 64-byte transaction.  (Or even four XMM NT stores, or hopefully even eight `movnti` stores in the kernel without having to use `kernel_fpu_begin()`.)

Comment: Thanks Peter - I made the mistake of rewriting the code into SO instead of doing a direct copy/paste which explains the typos. I updated the code above and listed a few assumptions that I have since confirmed. I took your advice and replaced `vmovdqa` with `vmovntdq` and added register clobbers, but I am still seeing the same behavior. I checked on the FPGA side of things and I am not seeing any issues such as a malformed TLP or poisoned packet. Unfortunately my expertise is with FPGAs and not kernel code, so I am nearing the end of my debugging abilities on the c++ side of things.

Comment: Your Godbolt links are still super-broken code, at least the second.  https://godbolt.org/z/eofMfqWjo is the code from the 2nd code block with some #defines to make it compile.  IDK much about drivers or PCIe I/O, so if what you're doing doesn't work, IDK.  You didn't describe how you mapped this memory into user-space; you're sure the mapping is WC?  WB memory can be a problem for device memory or especially MMIO registers.  (Although I thought I'd read that the symptom of using WB for MMIO regions was a crash or lockup, not lost transactions.)

Comment: You said the address is 32-byte aligned, but if you want it to go out as a single 64-byte transaction, it needs to be 64-byte aligned, doesn't it?

Comment: I have code that does exactly this, using WC memory and vmovdqa for the stores. Have you confirmed that the memory is actually mapped as WC by verifying the value of the PAT MSR and the values of the PAT, PCD, and PWT bits in the PTEs? By default there is no field in the PAT that contains WC, although I think Linux puts WC at PAT entry 1.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added in the code that I'm using to map the memory. I confirmed that the memory mapping is indeed WC in the PAT.

Comment: @prl The PAT MSR shows that the memory is mapped as WC. I am unsure how to check the PTE, though. Wouldnt the PTE align with the PAT?

Comment: PAT (https://docs.kernel.org/x86/pat.html) is a per-page thing; there aren't MSRs for each page separately, just to determine which of PAT and MTRR are enabled.  That MSR doesn't set write-back vs. write-through vs. write-combining vs. fully uncacheable (strongly ordered) for any individual pages, it's the bits in the page-table entries that do that.